# php fopen fwrite error

Tags: php, permissions, fwrite, chmod

What is wrong with this code?

```
<?php
$timestamp = time();
echo time();
echo "<br>";
$datenbank = "timestamp.txt";
$datei = fopen($datenbank, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($datei, $timestamp) or die("Unable to write file!");
fclose($datei) or die("Unable to close file!");
?>
```

I'll get only "Unable to write file!". The file has 777 permission.

Comment: What is the output here: `if(is_writable($datei)) echo "yes"; else echo "no";`

Comment: @Rizier123 is writable..

Comment: Delete the file and try the script again, and if it doesn't create the file, you don't have enough permission in the current dir

Comment: Directory relevance? Try `fopen(getcwd().'/'.$datenbank, "w")`

Comment: @Rizier123 it created the file. But now it says no to is_writable..

Comment: @DeDee fopen() works without any problem.. The only problem is fwrite()..

Comment: @FrederikGreve oh my mistake. Try then both, my previous suggestion and `fwrite(getcwd().'/'.$datei, $timestamp)`. In some scenarios you could be executing the script with the current directory in another scope. It's only to make sure the file in both cases is accessed in current directory.

Comment: @DeDee "Unable to write file"..

Comment: Check chmod for more correct option.

Comment: @DarshanJain I don't know what you mean..

Comment: @DarshanJain. Stated already that the file CHMOD is 777, later on the script recreated the file so the current user is the owner.

Comment: After a restart of apache everything works fine. I don't know why..